# Goland Debugger not working with go version upgrade ( v1.11 -> v1.13) on mac

Tags: go, goland

I upgraded golang from v1.11 to v1.13 in mac (mojave OS). The debugger started throwing error `Test framework quit unexpectedly`. The console output was

```
API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:xxxxx
Version of Delve is too old for this version of Go (maximum supported version 1.12, suppress this error with --check-go-version=false)

Debugger finished with exit code 1
```

I am unable to use debugger on goland since then, however delve as cli command is working. Dont know how to proceed? Also I cannot find any option to disable --check-go-version in goland?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update your IDE to GoLand 2019.2.2 or newer and the issue will be solved.